# JS RegExp.test() not working?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following code and I'm not sure why both tests are not passing. I think it is because of "/" characters in URL. Could someone please help me figure out how to escape them?

```
var myURL = "/late-model/products/air-management";

// Test String.match()
if(myURL.match(/late-model/gi)) {
    jQuery("#pass").append("String.match() passed!<br>");
}

// Test RegExp.test()
var regex = new RegExp(myURL, "gi");
var keyword = "late-model";
if(regex.test(keyword)) {
    jQuery("#pass").append("RegExp.test() passed!");
}
```

Available at [jsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/a2s6vqgs/).

Comment: `new RegExp(myURL.replace(/\//g,'\\/'), "gi");`

Comment: Oh, wait, you've reversed the test, checking for the url in the keyword

Comment: haha, shoulda waited and posted answer. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might you have the pattern and the test string reversed in the second test?

```
var keyword = "late-model";
var regex = new RegExp(keyword, "gi");
if(regex.test(myURL)) {
    jQuery("#pass").append("RegExp.test() passed!");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a2s6vqgs/1/

Comment: I like the answer, thank you! However, could you explain why that is?

Comment: Sure, when you create a RegExp like that, you are giving it the pattern you are looking for.  When you call `test()` you are giving it the string to search in.  In your case you want to search in `myURL` for  the pattern "late-model".  Hope that helps ;)